# A particle following the curve traced out by the path $c(t) = \left(\sin\left[e^{t}\right], t, 4-t^2\right)$ flies off on a tangent at time $t = 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A particle following the curve traced out by the path $c(t) = \left(\sin\left[e^{t}\right], t, 4-t^2\right)$ flies off on a tangent at time $t = 1$. Find the position of particle at time $t = 2$.

Solution:

$$C(t) = \left(\sin\left[e^t\right], t, 4-t^2\right),\qquad C'(t) = \left(e^t\cos\left[e^t\right], 1, -2t\right)$$

$$C(1) = \big(\sin[e], 1, 3\big),\qquad C'(t) = \big(e\cos[e], 1, -2\big)$$

At $t = 2$ the parametric is

$$[x, y, z] = \big(\sin[e], 1, 3\big) + \big(e\cos[e], 1, -2\big)(2-1)$$

so

$$(x, y, z) = \big(\sin[e] + e\cos[e], 2, 1\big)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct